# Android Studio and Getting Maps Correctly installed

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio, but I currently get this error:

> error: package com.google.android.gms.maps does not exist

Now, if I in 
**project/module/build.gradle** I do this

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile files('src/main/libs/google-play-services.jar') }
```

I currently get this error:

> Could not find method
>   android.webkit.WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled

And earlier I got this

> Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'

Whatt is the correct thing to do here / how do I solve above errors?

For reference: I orignally manually converted this project form a broken Eclipse project - sadly, for both Eclipse builds and Android Studio builds, it is the map/library thing that I seem unable o solve. The app is otherwise still working as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
compile files('src/main/libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
```

or use newer version if you want.

You need to have Google Play Services downloaded in SDK.